# Assign a model to another model using ModelChoiceField

Tags: django

I am new to Django and would like to create a platform where teachers can create student profiles and assign reports to the specific student.

Therefore, I have made two models (Student & Report) and two CreateViews. When creating a report, the teacher has the option to select a student from a choice field. This I have done using `ModelChoiceField`. However, when submitting the report model, the students name is not saved to that model. How can I accomplish this?

Ultimately I would like to have a profile to each student showing their info and reports attached to their model.

models.py

```
class Student(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, default="")
    age = models.CharField(max_length=2, default="", blank=True)


class Report(models.Model):
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

forms.py

```
class StudentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(StudentForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        model = Student
        fields = ['name','age',]

class ReportForm(forms.ModelForm):
    student = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Student.name, initial=0)

    class Meta:
        model = Report
        fields = ['title','file','player',]
```

views.py

```
class StudentCreate(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Student
    template_name = 'student_create.html'

    form_class = forms.StudentForm

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)

class ReportCreate(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Report
    template_name = 'report_create.html'
    form_class = forms.ReportForm

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

Comment: Your `Report` model needs to have a `ForeignKey` to `Student` if you want to save this relation.

Comment: That works, thanks. If you would like to make it an answer, I can accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently your `Report` model is like so:

```py
class Report(models.Model):
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

The basic concept behind a model is that it is an abstraction / design of how we want the database table for some entity to look like. So the fields we add in a model are **columns / attributes** in our database table. If we want to store some data we need to have some column for it (or in terms of models a field).

Your model `Report` has no field for storing some student (in essence a foreign key to a `Student`, a foreign key is basically a pointer to a particular entry of another table). So you should add that to your model:

```python
class Report(models.Model):
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    student = models.ForeignKey(Student, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="reports")
```